How to create a service connection to External Entra Id?
In Azure Devops I use the AzureCLI@2 task in my pipelines to run scripts. In Azure I've a subscription with multiple tenants. I've created service connections in Devops for each of these tenants. In the pipeline I can provide the service connection as an argument to AzureCLI@2 and it runs the script in that tenant as expected.
Now I've added an External Entra Id tenant to my subscription and I'd like to run scripts in that tenant as well, but I cannot create a service connection to this tenant.
Is it even possible to do that? How?

when you create a new service connection (manual, do not use automatic) you can specify the tenant

Is the suggestions in the answer working for you? @ErikZ

@BrightRan-MSFT not really. I had to create a new subscription and connect it to the  external entra tenant. In the subscription I had to assign the contributor role to my service principal. I wish I didn't have to create a new subscription. I can't see how managemant groups can solve this.

Az login allows tenant level access with the switch --allow-no-subscrition. I wish I could make a service connection that way.

When your Azure DevOps organization is not connected to a Microsoft Entra ID tenant, if you want to set up an ARM connection (Azure Resource Manager service connection) in your organization to access the Azure resources from that tenant, you can do like as below:

On Azure Portal, in your external Microsoft Entra ID tenant, go to "Microsoft Entra ID" > "App registrations", to check if there is an existing App registration owned by you. If not, create a new one. Ensure you have assigned the App registration with the required roles on the Azure subscription so that it has the access to the Azure resources under the subscription in the external tenant.


On Azure DevOps, in the project where your pipelines are, go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create a new ARM connection. Select "Azure Resource Manager" > select "Workload Identity federation (manual)". Give a customized name to the service connection to complete Step 1. Click "Next" to open Step 2.


Open the App registration created above. Go to "Certificates & secrets" > "Federated credentials" tab to add a new credential. Fill in the required information on the new credential.

Federated credential scenario: Other issuer
Issuer: Copy from Step 2 on the new ARM connection window.
Subject identifier: Copy from Step 2 on the new ARM connection window.
Name: A customized name of the new credential.



Back to the new ARM connection window to complete Step 2.

Scope Level: Select Subscription if you want this ARM connection can only access resources under the specified Azure Subscription.
Subscription Id: The ID of the Azure Subscription.
Subscription Name: The name of the Azure Subscription.
Service Principal Id: The Application (client) ID of the App registration created above.
Tenant ID: The Tenant ID of the external tenant.




After completing above steps, in your pipelines, you can use this ARM connection on the AzureCLI@2 and other Azure related tasks to connect to your external tenant and access the resources under the specified Azure Subscription.

EDIT:
If you do not have any Azure subscription in your external tenant, you can consider using Azure management group:

As mentioned above, go to "Microsoft Entra ID" > "App registrations" to create an App registration if there is no any existing one owned by you in your external tenant.

Create a management group in your external tenant on Azure Portal. Assign the App registration with some roles (Reader at least) on the new management group.

When creating the new ARM connection, select "Workload Identity federation (manual)" (same as above step #2).

Open the App registration and go to "Certificates & secrets" > "Federated credentials" tab to add a new credential (same as above step #3).

Back to the new ARM connection window to finish Step 2.

Scope Level: Select "Management Group".
Management Group ID: The ID of your management group created above.
Management Group Name: The name of your management group created above.
Service Principal Id: The Application (client) ID of the App registration created above.
Tenant ID: The Tenant ID of the external tenant.




After above configuration, you should be able to "Verify and save" the new ARM connection.
In the future, if you add some new Azure subscriptions into the external tenant, you can move the subscriptions under the management group, and assign roles to the App registration on each subscription. Then, in Azure DevOps pipelines, you can use the ARM connection to access these subscriptions which have been added to the management group.


Thank you, but my External Entra Id is not connected(?) to a subscription. Because of that I'm not able to do 'verify and save' in the last step.
When using logging in to the tenant using az I have to use the --allow-no-subscription argument.
az login --tenant xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --allow-no-subscriptions

@ErikZ, If you do not have any Azure subscription in your external tenant, you can consider using Azure management group. See EDIT for more details.
